# Draw shape according to the pre-defined paths by touch in iOS4 SDK

Tags: ios, ios4

I was trying to make an iPhone app which asks players to draw line according to the red dotted line as illustrated in the image using `SINGLE TOUCH`. My question is: **How to check whether the user has complete the path ( need not to be accurate ) ?** p.s. I'm using iOS4 SDK

[image: what I'm trying to do, illustrated]